# Unable to complete the operation while pushing a new controller

Tags: swift, xcode, navigation

I am trying to navigate into a new controller, but I am getting the following error:

```
error The operation couldn’t be completed. (placesapi error 16.)
```

I have tried a couple of ways to do it, but the error persists.

**Attemp1**

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(MainViewController(), animated: true)
```

**Attemp2**

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let mainViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainViewControllerID") as! MainViewController
    self.present(mainViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The identifier of the controller is set as the image shows:

[image]

**Solve**

After cleaning my project and changing the name of the `navigationController` as Frankenstein mentioned, the navigation works. Note that cleaning was required.

Comment: Are you using any google APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the `story-board` name and not the `view-controller` name:

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let mainViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainViewControllerID") as! MainViewController
```

Edit: Make sure your `Main.storyboard` file has a `ViewController` whose class is set as `MainViewController` and identifier is set as `"mainViewControllerID"`

Comment: I have also tried to use  Main as the name of the storyboard file (Main.storyboard) but it keeps failing. Do I need to create a transition also in that file? I mean by dragging and selecting show (I am new with iOS, so I am not really aware about the navigation concept). A priori, I thought that I was creating this transition within my code, but maybe needs to be also in the storyboard file

Comment: Hey, I have clean my project and now it runs. I will mark your correct as correct, since you were also right regarding tha name of the storyboard